# Lift XML Parsing Error

Tags: xml, scala, lift

I know there are other questions on this and I have read through almost all of them and none of them solved my problem.

I have inside a home directory:

```
   def search(in: NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {

     bind("work", in,
      "docId" -> text("", did = _),
      "visitId" -> text("", vid = _),
      "provider" -> text("", prov = _),
      "emCode" -> text(ecode, ecode = _))
    }
```

along with:

```
<lift:home.searchForm form="POST" multipart="true" >
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>DocId</td>
     <td>VisitId</td>
     <td>Provider</td>
     <td>EanMCode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

     <td><work:docId /></td>
     <td><work:visitId /></td>
     <td><work:provider /></td>
     <td><work:emCode /></td>
     <td><button>Click Me!</button></td>

    </tr>
   </table>
  </lift:home.searchForm>
```

Inside an html page.  I have included  xmlns:lift="http://liftweb.net/" in default.... I can't find anyway to fix this... I am getting

```
XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
Location: http://localhost:8080/
Line Number 29, Column 10:     <td><work:docId></work:docId></td>
```

in firefox.  I have written similar code and had it working in another app and just cant even find anything im doing different thats not trivial naming...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I change all the "work" words to the letter e... i get the same error.  But if change it to the letter l... it doesnt get a parsing error but nothing shows up.  Am I missing some keywords from xml or something that are just slipping my mind?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're invoking the snippet `home.searchForm` but your method is `search`.  Change your method name to `searchForm` and it should be okay.

Also, please upgrade to Lift 2.0... 2.0 has much better error reporting and will flag this kind of issue in the browser.

Thanks.